# Load model like a refresh without ember-data

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a little ember app without using Ember-Data (using TheMovieDB API) and I don't understand why model is not load when I click on a `{{#linkTo}}` link, but when I refresh the page manually datas are loaded correctly.

Here is my App.js :

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('movie', {
    path: '/movie/:movie_id'
  })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        var movies = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=5b088f4b0e39fa8bc5c9d015d9706547",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                var length = data.results.length;

                data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                    if (item.backdrop_path != null) {
                        var tmp = item.backdrop_path;
                        item.backdrop_path = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/"+tmp+"?api_key=5b088f4b0e39fa8bc5c9d015d9706547"
                        movies.push(item);
                    }

                })
            }
        });

        controller.set('content', movies);
    }
});


App.MovieRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (param) {
        var infos;
        /* Important !! */
        var promise = Ember.Deferred.create();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+param.movie_id+"?api_key=5b088f4b0e39fa8bc5c9d015d9706547",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var tmp = data.backdrop_path;
            data.backdrop_path = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/"+tmp+"?api_key=5b088f4b0e39fa8bc5c9d015d9706547";
            // infos = Ember.Object.create(data)
            promise.resolve(data);

        }
    });
    console.log("MODEL");
    return promise;
},
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});

App.Movie = Ember.Object.extend({})
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you show your template where your `linkTo` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified which model you mean, I'm assuming you mean the `movie` model, and with my assumption I'm trying to answer.

I think your problem is that your template expects the model coming from a `MovieIndexController` because you specified a `resource` in your router map instead of a simple `route`.

That said, the solution might be to rename your controller to `MovieIndexController` and respectively the route `MovieIndexRoute`.

Here the [reference](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) my answer is based on, under the paragraph **Resources**.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry I don't specified, but I tried your solution and change `this.resource('movie')` into `this.route('movie')` but both still don't work.

Comment: mmm, could create a fiddle? It would make it easier to find the problem I guess.